# Using WebStorms IDE is it possible to run only one unit test from a unit test suite?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, webstorm

When using WebStorms as a test runner every unit test is run. Is there a way to specify running only one test? Even only running one test file would be better than the current solution of running all of them at once. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Mocha.

Comment: @Rob, I'm using Mocha, edited the question to show that (was hoping it wouldn't make a difference)

Comment: It's possible, but using a regular node.js run config (not mocha), see here: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/01/17/debugging-mocha-unit-tests-with-webstorm-step-by-step/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-10067](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10067)

Answer (score 1):

You can double up the i on it of d on describe and the runner will run only that test/suite. If you prefix it with x it will exclude it.

There is a plugin called ddescribe that gives you a gui for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--grep <pattern>` command-line option in the Extra Mocha options box on the Mocha "Run/Debug Configurations" screen. For example, my Extra Mocha options line says:

```
--timeout 5000 --grep findRow
```

All of your test *.js files, and the files they `require`, still get loaded, but the only tests that get run are the ones that match that pattern. So if the parts you don't want to execute are tests, this helps you a lot. If the slow parts of your process automatically get executed when your other modules get loaded with `require`, this won't solve that problem. You also need to go into the configuration options to change the  every time you want to run tests matching a different pattern, but this is quick enough that it definitely saves me time vs. letting all my passing tests run every time I want to debug one failing test.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the tests within a scope when you have a Mocha config setting by using [.only](http://jaketrent.com/post/run-single-mocha-test/) either on the describe or on the it clauses

I had some problems getting it to work all the time, but when it went crazy and kept running all my tests and ignoring the .only or .skip I added to the extra mocha options the path to one of the files containing unit tests just like in the example for [node setup](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/01/17/debugging-mocha-unit-tests-with-webstorm-step-by-step/) and suddenly the .only feature started to work again regardless of the file the tests were situated in.